# How does the referral system work?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

I don't understand how the referral program works even after reading everything about it. Do I only get the 500 CC if the referred person subscribes within 14 days, or if I just refer the person? And do I get 500 CC for every month that referred person subscribes, or is it just one time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two types of referrals:

1. You, as a subscriber, refer a past or present subscriber who has never been referred before.  (The page says they can't have been referred within the past 90 days, but unfortunately it doesn't work if they've ever been referred period.)
2. You, as a subscriber, refer someone who creates an entirely new F2P account with your referral link.

In my experience, #2 rarely works (the system is not very reliable).  But when it does, they just get a "Jumpstart Bundle" with a few utility items.

In the case of #1, they get a "Preferred Friends Bundle" with 7 days of free sub time and some utility and cosmetic items.

As for what **you** get: In the case of #1 for a current sub, and in both cases if they subscribe within 14 days, you get **500** Cartel Coins (one time).  For every month they subscribe after the first month, you get **100** Cartel Coins.

More details: http://www.swtor.com/info/friends

<sub><sub>[My profile](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/6066/matthew-read?tab=profile) has my referral link for anyone who wants a referral.</sub></sub>

Answer (score 1):

- Previous Subscribers who have been unsubscribed for 90 days or more are eligible to participate in the Friends of SWTOR program. If they participate, they cannot be referred again for 90 days.
- If you’re a new player, opt-in for email communication from Star Wars: The Old Republic is required

For returning Subscribers, rejoining the Game through the Friends of SWTOR program offers exclusive benefits including seven days of subscription level access, a Preferred Status Bundle with special customization and convenience unlocks, and one Complimentary Character Transfer for the lifetime of the account.

For new players, the Jumpstart Bundle includes:

- 1x Quick Travel Pass – A single-use pass to use your planet's Quick Travel network without a cooldown. When consumed, it grants your character a single-use pass with a duration of 60 minutes.
- 5x Minor XP Boost – Increases experience gained from all sources by 25% for 1 hour. This Boost will not stack with other Experience Boost consumables.
- 1x Inventory Module – Adds 10 additional Inventory slots. Using this item immediately grants additional inventory space, to a maximum of 80 slots.

For previous Subscribers, the Preferred Friends Bundle includes:

- Unlock: Inventory Module – Adds 10 additional Inventory slots. Using this item immediately grants additional inventory space, to a maximum of 80 slots.
- Unlock: Crew Skill Slot – This item will grant an additional Crew Skill slot to a maximum of 3.
- Customization Control: Character Display Titles – Unlocks access to display Character Titles that you have earned. Show off your accomplishments and gain recognition with this unlock.
- Customization Control: Unify Colors – Unlocks the ability to unify the colors of your equipment. This cosmetic feature. This cosmetic feature allows you to determine your character’s look.